# Issue with Azure-TFS build in the case multiple websites in single webrole

Tags: .net, azure, build, tfs, webrole

I have been using and publishing multiple websites in single web role without any issues.
Then I tried implementing continuous delivery with Team foundation service as mentioned in 
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-tfs/
But the problem started when i tried to use 
(azure)TFS builds. The build always fails when compiling the secondary site.

There are no issues when manually packaged and deployed or packaging and deploying using powershell scripts.
 Earlier to overcome the issue of secondary sites not publishing I used the solution mentioned in this blog [michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/multiple-sites-in-a-web-role/](http://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/multiple-sites-in-a-web-role/) and it worked fine.
Now TFS builds fail with or without this hack.

When I checked the build drop folder I noticed that the TFS builds create a folder only for the web role and not for the secondary sites and when the build script looks for that folder of secondary website it fails as there is none.

Any solution for this issue is welcome.

More info--

This is a cloud service and not an azure web site. This web role is part of  set of worker and web roles which are deployed together in a deployment.

I used the AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml template.
I configured the  Deployment Settings Name as the cloud service name.
And filled in the details of  Step 5 - Publishing -- Azure Cloud service as per my deployment setup.
I left the step 6 - Publishing Azure website empty as this is not an azure website.

The error anyway is happening during the build of the web role with the secondary website .

Error format

: Cannot find the physical directory 'C:**Secondary Website Project Name**' for **virtual path Secondary site name configured in Service definition file**./.

Comment: i did not investigate this further.instead i moved the secondary website onto a separate webrole.

Comment: I also ran into this issue today.  It appears the secondary site paths are messed up somehow.  I am able to build/deploy fine from my local machine to azure.  Please post if anyone has some insight.

Comment: @BillChristenson No solution yet.I occasionally read up on this.kinda not looking it seriously.  I see that you've posted to the same msdn forum posts too :)

Comment: @Aravind Yup.  This is the issue that's holding up our continuous deployments to Azure atm.  For now, we are manually deploying.  Hopefully someone will find a solution soon.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that VSO does not support deployment of multiple websites to an Azure Web Role.

Confirmation [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/c000812b-1118-4380-b80c-732b7b9f9ff2/issue-with-azuretfs-build-in-the-case-multiple-websites-in-single-webrole?forum=azuretfs) by Trevor Hancock.

I went ahead and suggested it as a new feature [here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5020886-support-deployment-of-multiple-websites-to-an-azur).

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working pretty well for me.  It allows you to use TFS build to publish multiple sites in a single web role.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidhardin/archive/2013/01/18/building-and-packaging-virtual-applications-within-azure-projects.aspx