# How can I publish an Azure Cloud Services project with multiple sites on a single service using Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-cloud-services

I have a classic Cloud Services project that has multiple websites on a single service, configured in `ServiceDefinition.csdef` like so:

```
<WebRole name="PE.Roles.API" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="API" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\PE.Roles.API">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="http" endpointName="PE.API" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
      <Site name="PE.Services.Authorization" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\PE.Services.Authorization">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="http" endpointName="PE.Services.Authorization" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    <!-- Etc -->
    </Sites>
</WebRole>
```

This compiles and packages correctly in Visual Studio 2015, and deploys without a problem from a precompiled `.cspkg` file to the Cloud Service.

We have recently moved to Visual Studio Team Services for DevOps, and I'm trying to set this solution up to build and deploy in the cloud, using the provided Azure Cloud Services build template.

The `.sln` build step completes correctly, but the `.ccproj` build step fails with the following error:

```
PE.Azure\bin\ServiceDefinition.csdef (0, 0)
PE.Azure\bin\ServiceDefinition.csdef(0,0): Error CloudServices079: Cannot find the physical directory 'D:\a\1\PE.Roles.API' for virtual path API/.
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```

My build arguments are: `/t:Publish /p:TargetProfile=$(targetProfile) /p:DebugType=None /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:OutputPath=bin\ /p:PublishDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"`

I've found a number of blog posts and SO questions covering similar issues, but nothing that addresses this precisely (and nothing posted in the last few years).

**Update**

I've created a TFVC repo for the project and implemented the mapping step, as suggested below:

[image]

...but I still get the same error:
[image]

What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: I had this question few years ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869047/issue-with-azure-tfs-build-in-the-case-multiple-websites-in-single-webrole at that time I ended up with manual publish i think. later MS said it is supported in VS 2015 https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/5020886-support-deployment-of-multiple-websites-to-an-azur but the link given is a 404 now.  as such web apps are the popular ones these days than webroles.

Comment: Thanks. We're stuck with webroles for the time being. I did see your question, but I was hoping MS might have implemented this in the last four years.

Comment: You might have seen this post too. it says the code base is latest. but it does not really talk about VSO though.. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/samples/cloud-services-dotnet-multiple-websites-in-one-webrole/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify source mapping per to the setting of physicalDirectory.

Refer to this sample to modify it:

```
<Site name="API" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\WebGeneralDemo">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="http" endpointName="WebGeneralDemo" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
```

[image]

Update:

If these projects are in a git repository, you can keep the structure in repository like this:

-Repo

--AzureCloudServiceDemo

---AzureCloudServiceDemo

---WebRole1

--WebGeneralDemo

If the structure isn't like this, you can copy folders (include files) by using [Copy file task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-files)

**Update**

In the case of this specific question, the original structure of the Repo was as follows:

[image]

... where the `.ccproj` file is in the `PE.Azure` folder, and the site being published is in the `PE.Roles.API` folder.

The compiler was looking for the site content in the directory one *above* the `$(build.sourcesDirectory)` (so `D:\a\1\`), so the correct Copy File task to fix the error was:
[image]

A Copy Files task was required for each site, and the tasks had to be positioned after the Build Solution ***.sln step, but before the Build Solution ***.ccproj step.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That looks to be exactly what I need. Where do I find those mappings in VSTS?

Comment: (To be clear: I'm working with Git source control,not TFS. Are mappings available for Git?)

Comment: @JcFx Since your are using Git source control, you can keep the structure (check in my answer) in your repository. On the other hand, you can copy files and folder to have that structure by using Copy file task.

Comment: The Copy Files task worked for me, once I had figured out the correct path (../) to copy the files to. I've accepted your answer, and updated so it's clearer for anyone coming after. Thanks again.